# What's the output of this program supposed to be?

Tags: java

If you call this first method, 'CreateLotsOfAlphas', what is it supposed to print?  I'm just having trouble following the flow of the program.  I thought it would print aabbc, but for some reason it actually prints bacbc.

My reasoning is that newA1.y is just the input, a, at first due to the null.  a is saved into this.y, so newA2.y is (a + b) with b saved into this.y, then newA3.y is (b + c) to give aabbc.

Am I looking at this wrong or something?

```
public void CreateLotsOfAlphas() {
    Alpha newA1 = new Alpha(1.0, "a", null); 
    Alpha newA2 = new Alpha(2.0, "b", newA1); 
    Alpha newA3 = new Alpha(3.0, "c", newA2);
    System.out.println(newA1.y + newA2.y + newA3.y);
}
```

These two methods are in two different classes by the way.

```
public Alpha(double x, String y, Alpha oldAlpha) { 
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    w = (int) x;
    if (oldAlpha != null) { 
        oldAlpha.y = y + oldAlpha.y;
    } 
}
```

Comment: what is w? does it matter?

Comment: No, doesn't matter for this.

Comment: so it's NOT a SSCCE *sigh*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Alpha newA1 = new Alpha(1.0, "a", null);
// oldAlpha == null so we only newA1.y = "a"
Alpha newA2 = new Alpha(2.0, "b", newA1);
// oldAlpha is newA1 => newA1.y = "b"+"a"; newA2.y = "b"
Alpha newA3 = new Alpha(3.0, "c", newA2);
// oldAlpha is newA2 => newA2.y = "c"+"b", newA3.y = "c"; newA1.y = "ba" (still)
System.out.println(newA1.y + newA2.y + newA3.y);
// newA1.y = "ba", newA2.y = "cb", newA3.y = "c"
```

... clear enough?

Answer (score 1):

at the time of print statement

```
newA3.y = 'c'
newA2.y = 'cb'
newA1.y = 'ba'
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because of `null` in your first call to the constructor it's not able to enter into this if condition or if condition doesn't execute

```
if (oldAlpha != null) { 
        oldAlpha.y = y + oldAlpha.y;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Only if old Alpha is NOT null you actually print something.

```
Alpha newA1 = new Alpha(1.0, "a", null);  //no old Alpha
Alpha newA2 = new Alpha(2.0, "b", newA1); // newA1.y = bc as newA1 is Old alpha
Alpha newA3 = new Alpha(3.0, "c", newA2); // newA2.y = cb as newA2 is Old alpha
```

**SO:**

```
 System.out.println(
                newA1.y //bc as written above
              + newA2.y //cb as written above
              + newA3.y //only c as newA3 is never oldAlpha so it contains only self value
              );
```

I hope that is clear enough :).